# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, neural-network, quantile-regression

I'm working on a Quantile Regression Neural Network (QRNN) that can act as a forecaster for wind power as well as a detector for false data injection attacks.

I pretty much finished it but I am trying to quantify it's accuracy by taking the median quantile (tau = 0.5) and comparing it to the actual wind power by using an RMSE (while also trying to plot the actual wind power vs the median quantile). However, I keep running into issues with it.

Because q_hat (the predicted median quantile) is a numpy array and y_test (actual wind power test data) is a pandas dataframe, I have to convert y_test to numpy, but it's giving me this error:

"AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'"

**Here is the pinball_loss.py file that is needed for this code:**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
K.set_floatx('float64')

# pinball loss function with penalty
def pinball_loss(y, q, tau, alpha = 0.001, kappa = 0, margin = 0):
    """
    :param y: target
    :param q: predicted quantile
    :param tau: coverage level
    :param alpha: smoothing parameter
    :param kappa: penalty term
    :param margin: margin for quantile cross-over
    :return: quantile loss
    """

    # calculate smooth pinball loss function
    error = (y - q)
    quantile_loss = K.mean(tau * error + alpha * K.softplus(-error / alpha) )

    # calculate smooth cross-over penalty
    diff = q[:, 1:] - q[:, :-1]
    penalty = kappa * K.mean(tf.square(K.maximum(tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1], dtype=tf.float64)), margin - diff)))

    return quantile_loss + penalty
```

**Here is my code in Jupyter Notebook (I separated my cells by dashed lines for convenience):**

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense 
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data = pd.read_csv('2018 - Lillgrund (Sweden) Offshore Wind Farm Data.csv', header = [0,1])
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= [['local_time','output','windspeed'],['Europe/Copenhagen','kW','m/s']])

#Combine local time with Europe/Copenhagen and output with kW as one header.
data.columns = data.columns.map('_'.join)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Use the date column as the index.
data['local_time_Europe/Copenhagen'] = pd.to_datetime(data['local_time_Europe/Copenhagen'])

#Two weeks of data from 1/1/18 to 2/1/18 indexed hourly (744 total data points).
date_rng = (data['local_time_Europe/Copenhagen'] >= '2018-1-01') & (data['local_time_Europe/Copenhagen'] <= '2018-2-1 00:00:00')
data = data.loc[date_rng]

#Sets array as dates instead of row number
data.set_index('local_time_Europe/Copenhagen', inplace=True)

#Check to see index
# data.index
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# create lagged time series features
lags = range(1, 6) 
df = pd.DataFrame(data= data['output_kW'], index=data.index)
df = df.assign(**{'{} (t-{})'.format("Windspeed", t): data["windspeed_m/s"].shift(t) for t in lags}).dropna()

#Windspeeds are taken from hour before. i.e. original windspeed @ 6am was 10.124 m/s, windspeed @ t-1 (5am) is 9.596 m/s.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# create training and testing data
X = df.drop(columns=["output_kW"])
Y = df['output_kW']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#tau = np.arange(0.05, 1.0, 0.05) Original tau with multiple quantiles that I've already plotted
tau = 0.5 #Single point Quantile prediction
#N_tau = len(tau) #tau starts from 0.05 to 1, incremented by 0.05, which is 19 points.
N_tau = 1
N_features = 5 #Windspeed is the feature for X.
hidden_dim = 40 # number of hidden nodes
Lambda = 0.001 # L2 regularization

# loss function parameters (no need to modify)
loss_param={
    'tau': tau,
    'alpha': 0.01,
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def pinball_loss(y, q, tau, alpha):
    """
    :param y: target
    :param q: predicted quantile
    :param tau: coverage level
    :param alpha: smoothing parameter
    :param kappa: penalty term
    :param margin: margin for quantile cross-over
    :return: quantile loss
    """

    # calculate smooth pinball loss function
    error = (y - q)
    quantile_loss = K.mean(tau * error + alpha * K.softplus(-error / alpha) )

    return quantile_loss 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# add first layer to a sequential model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(hidden_dim,
                input_dim=N_features,
                kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(Lambda),
                activation='relu'))

# add output layer
model.add(Dense(N_tau))

# compile model
model.compile(loss=lambda Y, Q: pinball_loss(y = Y, q = Q, **loss_param), optimizer='Adam')

# fit the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000, verbose=0, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1);
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
plt.plot(history.history['loss']);
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss']);
plt.legend(('Loss', 'Val Loss'))
plt.ylabel('Loss');
plt.xlabel('Epoch');
plt.title("Training Loss");
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# estimate quantiles of testing data
q_hat = model.predict(X_test)
q_hat = pd.DataFrame(q_hat, index = X_test.index)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
N_PI = int(N_tau/2)
#y3 = y_test.to_numpy() #THIS ISN'T WORKING EITHER   
y3 = np.array(y_test)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
plt.plot(y3, color='red')
x = y3.index.values
for i in range(N_PI):
    y1 = q_hat.iloc[:,i]
    y2 = q_hat.iloc[:,-1-i]
    plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, color='blue', alpha=str(1/N_PI))
plt.title('RMSE: %.2f'% np.sqrt(sum((q_hat-y3)**2)/len(y3)));
plt.ylabel('Wind Power')
plt.xlabel('Time (hour)');
```

**The final cell above is where I get the following error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-338503ab24ea> in <module>
      4 plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
      5 plt.plot(y3, color='red')
----> 6 x = y3.index.values
      7 for i in range(N_PI):
      8     y1 = q_hat.iloc[:,i]

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
```

[Here is what the QRNN looks like with multiple quantiles vs the actual wind power (red line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0JJz.png)

[Here is what happens after the "Atribute Error" above when I try to plot the Median Quantile vs the Actual Wind Power (red line) with the RMSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2TjB.png)

I've also tried doing the following with the code where I made edits to the cell where I established tau and the last cell:

```
tau = np.arange(0.49, 0.51, 0.01) #Single point Quantile prediction
N_tau = len(tau) #tau starts from 0.05 to 1, incremented by 0.05, which is 19 points.
N_features = 5 #Windspeed is the feature for X.
hidden_dim = 40 # number of hidden nodes
Lambda = 0.001 # L2 regularization

# loss function parameters (no need to modify)
loss_param={
    'tau': tau,
    'alpha': 0.01,
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
N_PI = int(N_tau/2)

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
plt.plot(y_test, color='red')
x = y_test.index.values
for i in range(N_PI):
    y1 = q_hat.iloc[:,i]
    y2 = q_hat.iloc[:,-1-i]
    plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, color='blue', alpha=str(1/N_PI))
y3 = (y2.values+y1.values)/2 
#y3 is averaging the upper and lower quantiles, which is technically wrong since it isn't the median...
plt.title('RMSE: %.2f'% np.sqrt(sum((y3-y_test)**2)/len(y_test)));
plt.ylabel('Wind Power')
plt.xlabel('Time (hour)');
```

To which I get the following plot:
[This is when I do tau = np.arange(0.49, 0.51, 0.01) and N_tau = len(tau)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHoFM.png)

Although this looks correct and is pretty much what I want, there is another problem! Every time I restart the entire Kernel, the RMSE keeps changing (gets smaller by a little bit each time, i.e. from 15,000 to 14950 to 14830, etc.).

I am so close to finishing this, I just want to be able to validate the accuracy of my QRNN by comparing the median quantile with the actual wind power, but this part (which is probably a simple fix) is giving me a lot of trouble. Please help!

Comment: When using `y3.index`, what do you expect `y3` to be?  A Python list has an `index` method.  As the error shows a `ndarray` does not.  A pandas dataframe also has an `index`.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm attempting to convert y_test (which is the actual wind power output data) to a numpy array which is set equal to y3 so it's compatible with q_hat. What is the fix for this then?

Comment: @hpaulj What would I substitute `index` with for the `ndarray`? (I'm still kind of new to this stuff)

Comment: It looks to me like you expect `y3` to be a Pandas Series or DataFrame. It’s entirely possible you don’t need to convert it to an ndarray, you should check just to be sure. If you end up needing an array, the recommended way of doing so is using the recently introduced `.to_numpy()` method.

Comment: @AMC even when I do `y_test.to_numpy()` I still get the same `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'` error. However, if I don't covert to a ndarray and change the y3's in the final cell to y_test, I get a new error that says `ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without freq.`. Any fix for this?

Comment: @TariqJarrah What’s the type of `y_test` ?

Comment: @AMC when I do `type(y_test)`, it comes up as `pandas.core.series.Series`

Comment: I think you need to read more of `pandas` and `numpy` docs.